# No Cold Water in Shower

Tags: bathroom, water, shower, water-heater, hot-water

I'm not sure if this was ever asked here, but I've got a strange issue with my shower. It sounds weird, but I've been wanting to take cold showers lately to cut down on how much hot water I take up in the shower so others can enjoy showers. Honesly, I don't mind cold showers.

Here's the problem: My shower will always default to hot water. When I turn on the shower, it starts cold and then will start getting warmer until it's hot. I'm pretty sure it isn't my imagination because I've tried leaving it on for a while without touching the water (Of course, turning the lever enough to have it fully on, but not enough to get near the halfway mark) and it's been hot.

If you'd like to know more information about what kind of shower, let me know! I'm not the most advanced person when it comes to these kinds of things, but I'll try my best to specify! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you turn the handle all the way to one side or the other, do you get cold water at all?

Comment: @mmathis I'm not at my house at the moment, but I've tried it on all the way to the left (All the way on hot) and it doesn't get cold, but when I turn it all the way to the right it turns off. Whenever I turn it on just enough to be on all the way, but not enough to be in the middle (Usually halfway to the right) it will get cold for a while and then get warmer as it runs pretty quickly. I've noticed this problem in my house and, just last year, my college dorms which have the same type of handle for turning on the water. Is it possible that the rotating handles default to hot water?

Comment: How far is it from your house to your dorms? I wonder if there's something in the water supply that's causing mixing valves to fail...

Comment: Around a 30 minute drive. It's the distance from Phoenix to Tempe between the places.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the mixing valve is shot... if you can see the brand, any plumbing supply store (I wouldn't go to a big box store) will be able to sell you a replacement cartridge etc to rebuild it.  It's a pretty simple job.

Comment: Not sure why, but I couldn't find a brand at all. After about a couple of days though, the water started staying cold for whatever reason. My best guess is that it's Arizona and the outside is REALLY hot during summer.